# jQuery Date Picker on Multiple Fields using array notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using JS to generate a list of input fields that have the name of:

```
name="date_from[]"
```

The class, 'date_picker', is instantiated using:

```
$( ".date_picker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
```

When a new record is generated using JS the new input field does in deed display the Date Picker but the date selected is inserted into the first field, always.

Is there any solution, or maybe an option in the date_picker to make it insert into the currently selected field?

Comment: [I cannot duplicate this problem, see this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fN9xz/) - Please consider making something similar so we can see the scenario involved.

Comment: Ohgodywhy can you please write an answer so that I can give you credit for this. Helped me spot my error.

Comment: It turns out my Laravel code was adding an id to each input id="date_from[]". When I introduced this to your JSFiddle code it behaved the way I explained. I have since rebuilt the ID of each element in JS as I construct it to accommodate that. And it works

Comment: One other thing. If I add another row after the page has loaded datepicker will not pick this up. Is that correct? Should I reinitiate datepicker then?

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker has a `onClose` event wich provide a variable with the result. You need to take it, split it, and set it to your inputs :

```
var $input = $('input')
$input.datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  , onClose: function(dateText) {
        for (var i = 0, date = dateText.split('-'), item; item = $input[i];) {
            item.value = date[i++];
        }
    }
})​
```

Here is [a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/fWuw6/).